# Percent operator, string interpolation

Tags: ruby

Here's some code from Zed Shaw book :

```
formatter = "%{first} %{second} %{third} %{fourth}"

puts formatter % {first: 1, second: 2, third: 3, fourth: 4}
puts formatter % {first: "one", second: "two", third: "three", fourth: "four"}
puts formatter % {first: true, second: false, third: true, fourth: false}
puts formatter % {first: formatter, second: formatter, third: formatter, fourth: formatter}

puts formatter % {
  first: "I had this thing.",
  second: "That you could type up right.",
  third: "But it didn't sing.",
  fourth: "So I said goodnight."
}
```

I understand that `%{}` is `%Q{}` by default, and that is string interpolation. But what is the meaning of `%{}` inside double quote?

```
"%{first} %{second} %{third} %{fourth}"
```

And what is the meaning of this line?

```
puts formatter % {first: 1, second: 2, third: 3, fourth: 4}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "meaning". If you run the code in `irb`, you'll see what it does.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Neither are related to `%Q`.

The `%` between `formatter` and the hash is the [`String#%`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-25) method.

`"%{first} %{second} %{third} %{fourth}"` is a format string, see [`Kernel#sprintf`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Kernel.html#method-i-sprintf) for details.

Comment: Note: It's very important to not put spaces in these parentheses. Doing so will treat it like a static String instead of interpolating it.

Answer (score 13):

Just to expand a little on the original answer.

The common usage of `sprintf` (`String#%`) expects the values to be supplied in the same sequence as the formatting codes in the format string. The first value following the format string is used for the first substitution, the second value is used for the second substitution, etc.

```
sprintf("%d : %f : %d", 123, 456, 789)
=> "123 : 456.000000 : 789"
```

Ruby also supports reference by name in format strings. For formatting the substituted value, use the form `%<name>s`. This form expects a formatting code following the `>`. The order of the values (i.e., in the hash) doesn't determine where the values are used. The same value can be used more than once.

```
sprintf("%<foo>d : %<bar>f : %<bar>d", { :bar => 123, :foo => 456 })
=> "456 : 123.000000 : 123"
```

If you don't want to format the substituted value, you can use the form `%{name}`, which does not expect a formatting code. Anything following the `}` is treated as a literal rather than a formatting code.

```
sprintf("%<foo>s", { :foo => 456 })
=> "456"
sprintf("%{foo} : %{foo}s", { :bar => 123, :foo => 456 })
=> "456 : 456s"
```